# Surjective endomorphisms of Noetherian modules are isomorphisms.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I'm trying to solve this question:

[image]

I didn't understand why the hint is true and how to apply it. I really need help, because it's my first question on this subject and my experience on this field is zero.

I need some help.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Already proved [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145310/proving-that-a-semi-simple-and-noetherian-module-is-artinian).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For any $m\in M$, if you have $u(m)=0$, then you have
$$(u\circ u)(m)=u(u(m))=u(0)=0.$$
Therefore $\ker(u)\subseteq\ker(u\circ u)$. By the same argument, you have
$$\ker(u)\subseteq\ker(u\circ u)\subseteq\ker(u\circ u\circ u)\subseteq\cdots$$
which should look familiar if you have just read a chapter on Noetherian modules.