# Prove that surjective endomorphisms of modules over a commutative Artinian ring with unity are isomorphisms

Tags: ring-theory, modules

Let $R$ be a commutative Artinian ring with unity.  Prove that the surjective endomorphisms of every $R$-module are isomorphisms.

I have failed to sketch the proof for this.  I do not even have a source of reference.

Proof:

Since $R$ is semiperfect, it is decomposable into a direct sum of indecomposable local rings.  This implies that every $R$-module is finitely generated.

Comment: Are the modules assumed to be finitely generated?  Otherwise, consider the endomorphism of $R^{\oplus \mathbb N}$ that deletes the first coordinate and shifts everything else one position to the left.

Comment: If the module is finitely generated, then it will have finite length. This property holds for modules of finite length.

Comment: All nonzero rings have modules which aren’t finitely generated, so your last deduction is outlandish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is false as noted in the comments.

It is fixed if the module is finitely generated.  For then it follows that $R$ and $M$ are Noetherian, and that problem [appears many places on this site](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145310/proving-that-surjective-endomorphisms-of-noetherian-modules-are-isomorphisms-and?r=SearchResults).